# Create a web service, JPA entities and DB tables starting with XSDs

Tags: database, web-services, jpa, xsd, eclipselink

I'm working on a contract-first integration where I design the XSD&WSDL files first to provide to the customers to call a specific web service hosted on our servers. I also need to save the requests in DB tables (Oracle DB at first, others will be coming later) in a structured manner. I need to save all fields as separate columns and multiple occurence nodes should probably have their own tables etc.

I was thinking about creating WS stubs from the XSDs and tagging them as Entities for JPA, then creating the DB tables using these entities. I'm learning JPA (EclipseLink) and I was wondering if this would be the best approach.

So basically my question is: How would you both create the web service, JPA entities and DB tables when you start with a request/response XSD?

Thanks for all ideas.

Regards,
Gökhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using web service generated classes as JPA entities might seem to be good idea, but in practice it is going to be a nightmare to maintain.

It's much better to keep JPA layer and WebService layer separated.

JPA layer will be driven by optimal database design (things like relations, normalization/denormalization for performance reasons, usage of appropriate field types, primary key creation strategy, etc.)

On the other hand, Web Service layer is an external interface to your application (or part of the application), it will be either given to you or designed in such a way, so it is the most comfortable from the API usage point of view and it could be far from optimal from the JPA point of view.

Think what would happen if someone will tell you that WSDL is about to be changed, some fields will be moved from one class to the other. If web service generated classes are your entities you will have to also alter DB schema, migrate data, etc.

And vice versa. If you need to change your DB schema (for performance reasons, for instance), you will need to alter your application web service interface, I doubt web service users will be happy about that.

So, even if it means more work, keep JPA layer and Web Service layer separated, so you can change one part without altering another one.

In Model View Controller pattern JPA layers is a part of Model, Web service is just your View - they should not depend on each other to much.

Comment: Same thing I had in mind - you're definitely right about keeping the stubs separate for JPA and WS. I was also checking out the tools which generates table creation scripts from XSD files but none really proves to be too different than creating them myself, at least I have more control. My problem is that the web service request/response XSDs has too many multiple-occurence nodes, and some are two nodes deep so it is hard to model all of these relations since a table column can not be a table itself. I need to define separate tables for all multiple occurence nodes and add proper key columns

Answer (score 1):

I took a slightly different approach on [DoxDB](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/) as I had chosen JSON rather than XML as the document structure, though I don't think it is too far off from what you need (in fact when I started it I was using XML first).

## TL;DR version

Use LOBs to store your XML content.  Your JPA just has an `@Lob` annotation that you can load up your content into.

Use XSDs to validate your data coming from your transport using `Marshaller` which is invoked through your @WebService which provides CRUDL methods deal with the entry as a lob in the JPA entity.

Then tune for security and performance.

## More details

The thing to note is I don't map the Json/XML themselves into database fields and tables but instead I had one table with a "schemaname" column, a LOB and some ID (though currently it has a few extra fields for auditing and only performing logical deletes).  I searched around Stack Overflow and it seems the consensus was that it is better to have a single large table vs many small tables if the data is similar, in addition JPA does not support dynamic table names anyway.

Instead of JAX-WS, I chose JAX-RS (REST API), but that's just a transport layer and you can choose either one depending on your need.  In that layer I implement a CRUDL API that interacts with the JPA.  You can pass XML in JAX-RS as well you don't need to go WSDL if you don't want to.

Initial performance measures isn't too bad.  Loading up 100,000 rows took about a minute and doing single row retrievals is still in subseconds.  Retrieving and rendering 100,000 rows takes about 5 seconds. Of course there's no science with it and I doubt it will have that kind of performance in real life with a lot of load due to XA transactions, distributed friendly, security and little transitive dependencies.

One architectural decision I had made early on was [DoxDB](https://github.com/trajano/doxdb/) was not going to do searches on the database, instead that job is passed onto ElasticSearch which is called through their REST API rather than being embedded in the application (which would involve taking up their dependencies).  It's vendor specific, but at the moment I haven't found a better alternative.